# How to automatically put the APK into the asset after the build by android gradle script

Tags: android, build, apk, assets

I'm using DexClassLoader for dynamic loading class, and now, I need to copy APK file into the asset folder every time. is there any way to add automatically to android gradle script
Thanks

Comment: why you want to put  apk file into the asset folder ?

Comment: I need to provide my apk file to somewhere by contentProvider AssetFileDescriptor

Comment: And what I want is "copy apk file to assets folder after evey build automatically"

Comment: so you have two applications and you want to copy apk of application B to application A assets?

Comment: yes full scniro is this.

1. A(main) app catchs B(sub) app installation.

2. A requests apk file by contentResolver. and B provides apk(itself) at asset folder

3. A loads class dynamically from copied B apk.

at step 2, B apk is saved at assets folder after every build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a **python**, also make sure you already installed the python before doing this.

Create a python file in your root project.

**`build.py`**

```
import subprocess
import shutil
import os
import sys

# Call this function to build the apk via gradle.
def build_cmd():

    # This will build your debug apk.
    buildProject = "gradlew.bat clean --profile --recompile-scripts --offline --rerun-tasks assembleDebug";

    # If you want to build a release apk use this instead.
    # buildProject = "gradlew.bat clean --profile --recompile-scripts --offline --rerun-tasks assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=" + os.path.abspath("store_key.jks") + " -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=pass123 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=key_alias -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=pass123"

    # As of Python 3 use run() instead of call() function
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api
    subprocess.run(buildProject, shell=True)

# Call this function to move the builded apk to your desire directory.
def moveDir():
    # Get the generated apk
    apk_path = "./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"

    # apk will rename and move to asset directory
    shutil.move(apk_path, "./app/src/main/assets/app-debug.apk")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    build_cmd()
    moveDir()
```

Then run the **`build.py`** in the terminal

> `python build.py`

and wait until the gradle task finish.

**EDIT:**

Because **some members don't have python environment on this project** instead of using a script in python try to add some **task** in your **app/build.gradle**

```
android {

    // Some stuffs of yours....

    task copyAPKtoAsset(type: Copy) {
        from "/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk", "/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
        into "/src/main/assets/"
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        packageDebug.finalizedBy(copyAPKtoAsset)
    }
}
```

Build your project and check your **assets** directory after.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion but ..Should I run everytime before build ? then... there's no difference to copy apk file after build by hands

Comment: Instead of building the apk in android studio, you can build the apk via command and the additional of using this script is automatically copy the apk in your assets folder. Is that what you want right?

Comment: It's similar
But there are some members dont have python environment on this project
So.. I wanted to change gradle build script on the studio  if possible.